# Not able to retrieve seconds from SQL server using PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

I am new to php as well as SQL Server, so if my question is too trivial please bear with me. Our company just migrated database from MySQL to SQL Server 2008. I am having problem retrieving datetime properly from the database. The field in question is of datetime type. The code i use is -

```
$query = "select name,rdatetime from names order by name";
$result = mssql_query($query);
while($row=mssql_fetch_array($result))
{
  $name = $row["name"];
  $rdatetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($row["rdatetime"]));
}
```

When I print this `$rdatetime` it shows as `2014-03-07 16:17:00`. The `ss` part is always `00`, even when there are other values in the database. I even tried the `DateTime` object

```
$rdatetime = new DateTime($row["rdatetime"]);
echo $rdatetime->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

But the results are same. Can anyone tell me what can be the problem ?

Comment: Are u sure rdatetime field in DB has seconds stored ?

Comment: yes, it stores the current date time when the record was added including seconds. This is a value direct from database - 2014-03-03 16:51:55.000